# Pass /oauth/token parameters in body

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Hii I have implemented spring-security-oauth2 in my application. Everything is working fine. But the request goes for token is GET and the parameters are added as Url param. 
I want to make it Post request and pass param in Request body.

Is there anyway?

Comment: did you consider sending them in header?

Comment: @karthik Yes that can also be one option.